# Can I reference multiple versions of a Chef cookbook?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

Is it possible to reference multiple versions of a Chef cookbook within a recipe like the following where a recipe in one cookbook (foo) references multiple versions of a recipe in another cookbook (bar) where the version variable is populated before this block?

```
begin
    case version
    when ""
        include_recipe "cookbook-bar"
    when "1.0.0"
        include_recipe "cookbook-bar@1.0.0"
    when "1.0.1"
        include_recipe "cookbook-bar@1.0.1"
    else
        raise "Invalid Version: " + version
    end
rescue Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound
    raise "The Specified Cookbook Was Not Found: cookbook-foo-bar@" + version
end
```

In the `metadata.rb` file I have set the dependency like the following to hopefully pull in versions `1.0.0`, `1.0.1`, and `1.0.2` of `cookbook-bar`.

```
depends          "cookbook-bar", "<= 1.0.2"
```

But when I run it I still get the `CookbookNotFound` error for versions `1.0.0` and `1.0.1` of `cookbook-bar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, only one version of a cookbook will be pulled down on the node, the highest matching the dependency constraint.

If you need multiples version of a cookbook within the same run, you have a problem somewhere.

Comment: One use case might be a "clean up" recipe, where I want to do a clean up based on the last run version of the cookbook before I proceed.  Is the only option in this case to have the latest version of the "clean up" recipe know how to clean up from all the previous versions?

Comment: Nope, there's a lot of way, without a real use case it's hard to tell which one would better fit. The main consensus is to avoid this kind of changes and provision the target from scratch.